# Correct way to store repeated data in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database table which contains a list of questions with the fields:
'Subject', 'Questions' and 'Color'.

There are several subjects such as 'Maths' or 'Physics' and there are questions for these subjects in the 'Questions' field.

The 'Color' field contains a word such as 'Red' or 'Green' to tell my web application what colour theme to use for a subject so for example I may set Maths to have a colour theme of red and then all the records in the database with 'Maths' would have 'Red' in the colour field.

As you can imagine, with hundreds of questions (per user), the colour field is repeated a lot for each subject. Would it be more efficient to have another table which says what colour to use like so:

```
UserID | Subject | Colour
  91   |  Maths  |  Red
  13   | Physics | Green
```

Would this be unnecessary hassle or is this a better way of storing the colour of the subject then having the colour field in the first table which repeats say 'Red' for ALL of the 'Maths' subjects for that User?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unsure, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: In this exact case, I'd say that if you create a new table the only thing you will end up doing is saving bytes, and you are working with 4th normal form, which isn't really considered in practice.

Comment: So I would save data but it would make a whole lot of difference in terms on performance?

Comment: In this exact case, I'd say having a single table is faster than having two (since you'd be loading more data, and you would have to join the tables), but hey, it would be just miliseconds..

Comment: @fmbesteiro 4NF is certainly considered in practice by knowledgeable DBAs.  "3NF is good enough" is as misconceived as the idea that rows represent entities.

Comment: @reannb you may have a point.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize your table to create two: one that relates questions to subjects, and one that relates subjects to colours.  In your example code, you include UserID.  Will each user set their own colour?  If so, your example is correct.

The point of normalization is not to avoid storing a value multiple times (though using names as identifiers has many problems), but to avoid storing the association between values more than once.  Since each subject has one colour, the pair (Math, Red) should only be recorded once.

Answer (score 0):

As far a data normalization is concerned what you are doing is not a great example of doing this kind of task.

Make two tables

```
UserID | Subject | ColourID
  91   |  Maths  |  1
  13   | Physics |  2 
  14   | Physics |  2
```

and another table for colors

```
ColorID | Color 
  1     |  Red  
  2     | Green
```

This way you will not repeat the values of color for each subject in your first table.

Also, in future if you would want to give another color to any subject you will just have to change one value in your colors table.

I hope this makes sense..

Comment: Yes. Because this way you will have repeated numeric color codes rather than color text values. This will have two major benifits. 1) Easy to change subject color in future 2) You can index your main table on numeric color code.

Comment: Adding a surrogate key for colours is not normalizing.